# Which is faster: document.location.pathname or myOwnObj.pathname?

Tags: javascript, performance, oop

I'm trying to optimise my JavaScript code for speed.

I have certain attributes of the `document` object that I need to access frequently, like `document.location.pathname` or, even, worse, `document.documentElement.innerText`.

Which would be faster:

1. To access these attributes from `document` each time, or
2. To store them as attributes of one of my own objects, so that I can access them like `myObj.pathname` and `myObj.innerText`?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Really, try it. Create a micro-benchmark (e.g. http://jsperf.com) to satisfy curiousity .. then realize It Just Doesn't Matter in a realistic context.

Comment: I'm not sure how to. Also, I feel like it matters especially in the case of `document.documentElement.innerText`, because inuitively accessing the DOM and stripping away the tags should take longer than just accessing a string from an object.

Comment: Computers are *fast* and mainstream JavaScript/DOM implementations are *highly optimized*. Again, to settle your own curiosity, create your own benchmarks - if there are questions about *why* a benchmark yields "unexpected results", then that is a suitable SO question; this is not as there is no problem.. It really doesn't matter in any realistic program.

Comment: Theoretically #2 would be faster. In practice it probably wouldn't make much difference. Caching values in your own object only makes a real difference if you're caching the result of a method call, like `document.querySelectorAll(...)`.

Comment: And premature optimization strikes again,..

Comment: If you want to optimize for performance, the following doc page should keep you busy for a while... https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Test it.](http://jsperf.com/property-access-10)

While there are some differences across browsers, caching your objects does make the lookup faster.

"Faster" is in comparison with accessing the property of the object twice instead of once. I *really* doubt this is the bottleneck in your application. In any case, profile it before trying to optimize tiny things like this.

Comment: You're right, maybe I'm looking in wrong places for optimization. With `innerText`, however, there are some [huge performance differences](http://jsperf.com/property-access-10/2).

Comment: Sorry, I was too lazy to change variable names. I was testing `document.documentElement.innerText` cached vs. uncached. Try viewing it now.

Comment: @LonelyWebCrawler: Well, once you cache it, you're comparing the time it takes to get the `innerText` of an arbitrary element with the time it takes to lookup a variable in the current scope. Your question was about `document.documentElement.innerText` vs `cachedDocumentElement.innerText`.

Comment: My question wasn't about that-- `myObj` wasn't an element, it was just a regular object that had an attribute named `innerText`. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: @LonelyWebCrawler: In that case, there's even less reason to worry.